# Change quantity of product B based off of quantity from product A in Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I need to change the quantity of a free item based on how many of the main items are purchased. We sell razors. Currently when you buy a razor we add a free gift item. This gift item is 10 free blades. the problem I am having is if you buy 2 razors you still only get 1 free gift item. I need to change the quantity value in the hidden input field for the free gift based on the amount of razors they purchase. here is the code:

This part of the code checks the cart for the Razor and if it is in there it sets to true plus it grabs the number of razors purchased:

```
{% if item.product.tags contains '10bladesfree' %}
    {% assign free10blades = true %}
    {% assign razor_count = item.quantity %}
{% endif %}
```

This part of the code loops through the cart and adds the free gift if the Razor is in the cart. If the razor is not in the cart it removes the free gift:

```
{% if free10blades %}

<script>
if (typeof Shopify === 'undefined') var Shopify = {};
  Shopify.cart = {{ cart | json }};
  Shopify.toAdd = {{ linklistfree10blades.links.first.object.variants.first.id }};
  var pleaseAdd10Blades = false;
  Shopify.idsInCart = [];

  for (var i=0; i<Shopify.cart.items.length; i++) {
    Shopify.idsInCart.push(Shopify.cart.items[i].id);
    if (Shopify.cart.items[i].id !== Shopify.toAdd) {
      //console.log('add bouns item');
      pleaseAdd10Blades = true;
    }

  }

if (pleaseAdd10Blades && (jQuery.inArray(Shopify.toAdd, Shopify.idsInCart) === -1)) {
  var params = {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/add.js',
    data: 'quantity=' + {{ razor_count }} + '&id=' + Shopify.toAdd,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(line_item) { 
      window.location.href = '/cart';
    }
  };
  jQuery.ajax(params);
}
</script>
{% else %}
    <script>
      if (typeof Shopify === 'undefined') var Shopify = {};
        Shopify.cart = {{ cart | json }};
        Shopify.toAdd = {{linklistfree10blades.links.first.object.variants.first.id }};
        var pleaseRemove10Blades = false;
        Shopify.idsInCart = [];

        for (var i=0; i<Shopify.cart.items.length; i++) {
          Shopify.idsInCart.push(Shopify.cart.items[i].id);
          if (Shopify.cart.items[i].id === Shopify.toAdd) {
            pleaseRemove10Blades = true;
          }
        }

  if (pleaseRemove10Blades) {
    var params = {
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/cart/update.js',
      data: 'updates[' + Shopify.toAdd + ']=0',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(line_item) { 
        window.location.href = '/cart';
      }
    };
    jQuery.ajax(params);
  }
</script>
{% endif %}
```

I also have this code at the top of the page to create the hidden input field for the free gift:

```
{% if item.product.tags contains 'free-10-blades'%}
    <input type="hidden" name="updates[]" id="updates_{{ item.id }}" value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="0" data-id="{{ item.id }}">
{% else %}
```

Comment: Hi Jason, if the blades are free - why not use a line item property? a line item property simple appends a bit of data on a per product basis. Then  it wont matter what the quantity is, as it will always include the free blades.

Comment: Can't the client needs to keep track of the free gift with the sku in their fulfillment center

Comment: yes, but it is a free pack of blades

Comment: no, for each purchased razor the customer gets 1 free 10 blade pack

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103861/discussion-between-rob-and-jason).